# Football winners without scoring

Tags: knowledge, real

A football (soccer) team didn't score any goals, yet they still won the game. How is this possible?

Comment: I would say tournament rules, but I see Dmitry and suspect some math is involved.

Comment: actually no math this time. Just knowledge of how soccer works.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis good assumption, I'd say, haha

Comment: I can think of quite a few scenarios where this, sometimes regularly, happens - such as the game is the second leg, they win on penalties (doesn't count as a goal), the other team gets disqualified, the correct answer already given - or perhaps the most fun one, a ['Ghost Goal'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQZmRqxnH6M), where the ball goes through the side of the net and is given! However because of this I think this is probably a bit broad

Comment: You could also just let the referee kick the ball in, but will probably be disallowed by VAR because of FIFA rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because:

> The opposing team scored own goals themselves.

Comment: correct! that's the answer I was looking for. Quite recently Liverpool beat Leicester without scoring any goals :)

Answer (score 2):

> From the FIFA Disciplinary Code ([PDF](https://digitalhub.fifa.com/m/3ded0bb71aeb9931/original/krclgqjjwghm7hugwsar-pdf.pdf)):
>
> Art. 31 Forfeit
> 1 Teams sanctioned with a forfeit are considered to have lost the match by 0-3.
> 2 If the goal difference is greater, the higher score is upheld.